# How to disable parsing from parameter received in nuSOAP server

Tags: php, nusoap, soapserver

I have deployed a quick nusoap server, but some of the parameters that an operation receives will be pure XML text. (some other are strings and integers).

When the parsing takes places, it also affects the XML contained in the parameters's value, and it is converted to a php associative array.

Is there a way I can disable the parsing for some or all the parameters received in an operation?

Answer (score 0):

Just to answer my own question.. I can use inside the method a `global $server` if $server is the instance of the nusoap server and get the full answer by invoking `$server->document`